# Unable to call before_action method for IF condition in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

In my Rails code base, there is before action call for one specific method but I am not able to call it.

Sample code:

**ControllerCode**

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_country, only: [:index, :update]
  def index
    puts "Inside Index - #{@country}"
  end

  def update
    if true && book_my_ride
     puts "Inside Update - BookMyRide"
    end
  end

  def book_my_ride
    puts "Inside BookMyRide - #{@country}"
  end

  def set_country
    @country = "SampleCountry"
  end
end
```

When update method is called, because of before action - set_country is called.

But When control reaches to IF condition having 'book_my_ride' - System does not call 'set_country' method for book_my_ride.

Comment: Did you expect `set_country` to be called twice in that scenario? This is not how it works.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev - Got your point. By mistaken I have added book_my_ride for before_action

Answer (score 0):

Your book_my_ride method is executing a puts statement, and the output is nil. So I think what's happening is your logic there is really saying

```
if true && nil
  do something
end
```

This will never return true, so execution cannot continue. Try adding a return from that method, and see if the execution path continues correctly. Example:

```
def book_my_ride
    puts "Inside BookMyRide - #{@country}"
    return 'Called book_my_ride'
  end
```

I'm not sure what those puts statements are for - if they're just for debugging, I'd try using either

```
Rails.logger.info "debug statement here ..."
```

or use a return instead of a puts

```
return "Called #{__method__} --------"
```

The other good practice, if you're debugging, is create spec tests to verify the controller behavior.